# How do I remove duplicate code from titles.map and titles.slice?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I remove duplicate code from titles.map and titles.slice?
how should be handled with en effect to set the facets that should be displayed. Functionality works as expected, I just want to remove duplicated code.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const titles = [
    { id: "0", name: "Title" },
    { id: "5637144579", name: "Miss" },
    { id: "5637144576", name: "Mr." },
    { id: "5637145326", name: "MrandMrs." },
    { id: "5637144577", name: "Mrs." },
    { id: "5637144578", name: "Ms." },
    { id: "5637145330", name: "Br." },
    { id: "5637145327", name: "Dame" },
    { id: "5637144585", name: "Dr." },
    { id: "5637145331", name: "Fr." },
    { id: "5637144582", name: "I" },
  ];
  const [isAllFacets, setIsAllFacets] = useState(false);
  const MAX_FACET_COUNT = 5;
  const visibleFacetCount = titles.length - 1 === MAX_FACET_COUNT ? 
    titles.length : 
    MAX_FACET_COUNT;
  const showAllFacet = () => { setIsAllFacets(!isAllFacets); };
  return (<>
    {isAllFacets ? 
      titles.map((title: any) => { 
        return <div key={title.id}>{title.name}</div>; 
      }) : 
      titles.slice(0, visibleFacetCount).map((title) => { 
        return <div key={title.id}>{title.name}</div>; 
      })}
      {titles.length > visibleFacetCount && (<>
        {!isAllFacets ? (
            <button onClick={showAllFacet}>show all</button>
          ) : (
            <button onClick={showAllFacet}>show less</button>
          )}
      </>)}
  </>);
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the conditional operator to slice the entire existing array in case `isAllFacets` is false - instead of alternating over the whole JSX to return, alternate over only the index to slice.

A similar approach can be used to simplify your `<button>` text.

```
return (
    <>
        {
            titles
                .slice(0, isAllFacets ? titles.length : visibleFacetCount)
                .map(title => <div key={title.id}>{title.name}</div>)
        }
        {titles.length > visibleFacetCount && <button onClick={showAllFacet}>show{isAllFacets ? ' all' : ' less'}</button>}
    </>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal with `useMemo` hook. Prepare the data to display and render it. Value will be recalculated when anything inside `depsArray` is changed.

```ts
const titlesToDisplay = useMemo(() => {
  return isAllFacets ? titles : titles.slice(0, visibleFacetCount);
}, [titles, isAllFacets, visibleFacetCount]);

return (
  <>
    {titlesToDisplay.map((title) => {
      return <div key={title.id}>{title.name}</div>;
    })}
    {titles.length > visibleFacetCount && (
      <>
        {!isAllFacets ? (
          <button onClick={showAllFacet}>show all</button>
        ) : (
          <button onClick={showAllFacet}>show less</button>
        )}
      </>
    )}
  </>
);
```

Comment: agree with approach, but think `useMemo` harms readability without any benefit(`.slice()` is cheap operation and it does not look like referential equality affects anything either)

Comment: @skyboyer Honestly, for me it is just a way to separate jsx and actual logic and for me it actually improves the readability, JSX commonly gets messy with a lot of nestings and with useMemo it is easy to add any additional logic like filtering sorting, etc, without touching the JSX itself. Also areas of work separation, I work with logic and my collegue is doing scss+html only, less git conflicts :) And for this question useMemo is not about performance, `titles` are declared as a plain variable, so the array is recreated in each render and this useMemo hook is triggered on each render also.

Comment: but why not just `let titlesToDisplay; if (...) { titlesToDisplay = .... else { titlesToDisplay = ...` then?

Comment: @skyboyer I'd use ternar operator, but actually I'd convert `titles` to useMemo or useState, and this micro-optimization might save some cpu and dev time later. Like if i will need to pass this array to a hook or to use some kind of useEffect on it, to debug something with console.log or other side effect. I do agree that `slice` is fast and cheap operator but im a bit worried about unneded memory allocations and garbage collecting for each render. Maybe im doing some anti-pattern, but i prefer keeping everything wrapped with useMemo or useState or useCallback, no raw variables..

Comment: I have ambiguous feeling on this, from the one side looks like premature optimization and _may_(but not necessarily _will_) confuse a reader "why there is `useMemo`? should we care about referential equality? but where?". From the other side, it guarantees all the operations on this list will probably be kept in single place, without spreading across the component(due to team members' laziness and lack of code review :) )

Answer (score 1):

you only need to put all together :

```js
titles.slice(0, isAllFacets?titles.length:visibleFacetCount).map((title) => { return <div key={title.id}>{title.name} 
</div>; })
```

Comment: Sorry, but your answer looks like a cutted version of what @certainperformance suggested. No need to suggest the same code, that will lead to downvotes at min and account ban at max.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `renderTitle` function which returns the `title` `div`

```
const renderTitle = title => <div key={title.id}>{title.name}</div>
```

Then pass it to both `.map` invocations

```
titles.map(renderTitle)
```

and

```
titles.slice(0, visibleFacetCount).map(renderTitle)
```

And for your button, simplify it with:

```
<button onClick={showAllFacet}>show {isAllFacets ? "less" : "all"}</button>
```